# response status from server to client

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

In my app I want to respond from server to client the status of the operation, for example, from client sends data in format json to server and I want that this responds whit status of the operation, if these data have inserted correctly in database to send status 200,...

I now have this.

Client:

```
function sendAjax() {

        //I build the params necessary to send to server in format json

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "/url", 
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: param, 
            contentType: 'application/json',
            mimeType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) { 
                alert(data.id );
            },
            error: function(data,status,er) { 
                alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
            }
        });
        alert();
    }
```

Server:

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseJson post (@RequestBody String string){
     //I have the operations necessary to insert in database
    ResponseJson pruebaJson = new ResponseJson ();
    pruebaJson.setId (id);
    return pruebaJson;
}
```

ResponseJson.java

```
public class ResponseJson implements Serializable
{
    private String id;

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

How will I process the status that server send to client? this is, if I get status 200 or other status.

My app is realized in spring-mvc and I use javascript with ajax to send data in format json from client to server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by :

```
$.ajax({
         statusCode: {
           404: function() {
                alert( "page not found" );
            },  
           200: function() {
               alert("insert done..!!!");
           },
         }
     });
```

This may help you.

[See JQuery API for more option.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

EDIT : on the basis of my understanding you want to check status code inside success or error function for that

```
       success: function(data , textStatus, jqXHR) { 
            alert(data.id );  
            var statusCode = jqXHR.status  
            if(statusCode == 200 ){  
                //Your code execute if status is 200  
             }  
        }
```

like wise you can do it in error function also.

Comment: Ok, perfect, this has been useful for me, but I want to send from server to client the status for that the client in ajax function that I have to implement above it goes for success method or error method.

Comment: In client side I have implemented an ajax function that it sends the data in format json and this has the success method and error method and I want to implement in server side that if I insert well then I can send to client some code for that to execute in success method and if it inserts bad in database I can send an error for that to execute in error method. I don´t know if I explain well, sorry!!

Comment: @Ltcs I have added some code. pls check is it usefull or not?

Comment: First of all, the default behaviour of springmvc/your server is just what you wish I think. it sends 200 when ok, 404 when not found, 400 if bad request, 500 on internal server error and so on. However, you can control which status is being sent from server by using instances of `HttpServletResponse` in your controllermethods and set the status to match your needs, e.g. `response = HttpServletRespone.SC_BAD_GATEWAY ` hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call success function executes when server sends status 200 code. other than that your error function only executes.

If you want to handle error status separately you can handle in error function with   return status.